# QA team uses HP Quality Center, Dev team wants to use JIRA -- will this work?

Tags: bug-tracking, jira, issue-tracking, hp-quality-center

Our QA team uses HP Quality Center for defect tracking, test plans, etc.

The dev team really detests Quality Center and wants to use JIRA for internal task tracking.
Can these two systems work seamlessly together?

I have worked on projects where 2 teams used separate issue-tracking systems and keeping them in sync was a major headache.

Anyone have real-world experience integrating Quality Center and JIRA?

Comment: Current list of plugins
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?q=jira+quality+center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a 'bridge' between Quality Center and JIRA.  JIRA has APIs to allow you to build and/or customize these interfaces.  I have worked with Orasi, which has a bridge (no idea on the cost).

http://www.orasi.com/products/Pages/Orasi.aspx

http://www.beteoblog.com/2009/01/21/integrating-jira-and-the-hp-quality-center/

Answer (score 2):

QC has many, many, many features that are not in Jira. It would make this post horribly wrong even to list them. I've been working with QC for over 2 years, and although I'm not big fan of it, I must admit, that all those QC features allows it to support almost every QA activity (if tool and testing process are fully and properly implemented in organization).

As for the question, frankadelic you are right, maintaining QC defects and Jira Bugs in sync can be a pain. I would suggest:
a) look at orasi plugin for Jira [(link)](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/26467)
b) look at Go2Group plugin for Jira [(link)](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/8129)
c) write your own plugin for Jira

Unfortunately in my company none of those 3 solutions were implemented yet, so I can;' say much about them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by finding out whether it is inertia or specific functionality that makes them think they need to use different tools for very similar tasks. Changing tools is often easier than changing the way people think :-)

~Matt

Comment: Jira and QC support very different tasks. Or to be more specific QC supports more things than Jira.

Comment: Due to similar question I have explained it a bit more on programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46698/separate-trackers-for-features-and-defects/47035#47035

Comment: Use the smallest number of tools that will get the job done. Check you really need all the extra features to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a Jira-to-Quality Center bridge that can be purchased, but have no experience with using it.

Our QA group uses Quality Center for writing and executing test cases, but since our development group uses Jira for bug tracking, QA also uses Jira.

The disadvantage, from a QA perspective, is that there is no automatic connection between a bug and the test cases that discovered it, users must manually paste the path to the test case. As can be expected, sometimes this gets left out of the ticket.

I have worked on projects where Quality Center was used by both dev and QA for bug tracking. I felt like it provided a better connection between the bug and the specific testing that discovered it.

I don't know what advantage Jira provides to the development side, but I've yet to meet a developer that likes QC.

Comment: Even with test cases and bugs tracked through Quality Center, that doesn't necessarily always give you a link between them.  My experience of using Quality Center is that a substantial number of bugs either didn't relate to a test case (tester found bug exploring as any good tester does), or affected a large no of cases.  The most serious drawback was that even if you did link to a test case, it was useless to the developer as management would only pay for restricted QC licenses for them, so they couldn't access the test cases anyway. I've seen this approach in a couple of different companies.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried HP QC connector for Jira, and it has a nice UI and report for what we have synchronized, compared with other products, it's cheap.